# How to set value in a column based on values from another columns in the same table?

Tags: oracle, triggers, procedure, apex

I am quite new in ORACLE APEX and I would like to have a column BILANS that is a result of BUDGET and COST difference.
I mean I insert values to BUDGET and COST columns in a form and BILANS is counted automatically.
I think it should be quite basic feature but I cannot do it.
I tried to do this with trigger and procedure but I failed.
Underneath I will put my table, triggers and procedure that I try to create.

TABLE and triggers - work correctly

```
CREATE TABLE  "PROJECTS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAWYER_ID" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COST" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BUDGET" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "START_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "END_DATE" DATE, 
    "CREATED" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATED" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DEPTNO" NUMBER, 
    "BILANS" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "PROJECTS_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "BIU_PROJECTS" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON PROJECTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF inserting THEN
    INSERT INTO PROJECTS_ARCH
    (   
        ID
    ,   OLD_NAME
    ,   OLD_DEPTNO          
    ,   OLD_LAWYER_ID       
    ,   OLD_COST           
    ,   OLD_BUDGET                
    ,   OLD_START_DATE             
    ,   OLD_END_DATE   
    ,   NEW_NAME
    ,   NEW_DEPTNO         
    ,   NEW_LAWYER_ID     
    ,   NEW_COST          
    ,   NEW_BUDGET           
    ,   NEW_START_DATE            
    ,   NEW_END_DATE          
    ,   UPDATED    
    ,   UPDATED_BY  
    ,   MOD_TYPE   
    ) VALUES (
        PROJECTS_ARCH_ID_SEQ.nextval
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   :NEW.NAME
    ,   :NEW.DEPTNO         
    ,   :NEW.LAWYER_ID     
    ,   :NEW.COST          
    ,   :NEW.BUDGET           
    ,   :NEW.START_DATE            
    ,   :NEW.END_DATE  
    ,   SYSDATE
    ,   user
    ,   'INSERT'
    )
    ;
    END IF;
IF updating THEN
     INSERT INTO PROJECTS_ARCH
    (  
        ID
    ,   OLD_NAME
    ,   OLD_DEPTNO          
    ,   OLD_LAWYER_ID       
    ,   OLD_COST           
    ,   OLD_BUDGET                
    ,   OLD_START_DATE             
    ,   OLD_END_DATE    
    ,   NEW_NAME
    ,   NEW_DEPTNO         
    ,   NEW_LAWYER_ID     
    ,   NEW_COST          
    ,   NEW_BUDGET           
    ,   NEW_START_DATE            
    ,   NEW_END_DATE          
    ,   UPDATED    
    ,   UPDATED_BY  
    ,   MOD_TYPE   
    ) VALUES (
        PROJECTS_ARCH_ID_SEQ.nextval
    ,   :OLD.NAME
    ,   :OLD.DEPTNO          
    ,   :OLD.LAWYER_ID       
    ,   :OLD.COST           
    ,   :OLD.BUDGET                
    ,   :OLD.START_DATE             
    ,   :OLD.END_DATE    
    ,   :NEW.NAME
    ,   :NEW.DEPTNO           
    ,   :NEW.LAWYER_ID     
    ,   :NEW.COST          
    ,   :NEW.BUDGET           
    ,   :NEW.START_DATE            
    ,   :NEW.END_DATE     
    ,   SYSDATE
    ,   user
    ,   'UPDATE'
    )
    ;
    END IF;
IF deleting THEN 
     INSERT INTO PROJECTS_ARCH
    (  
        ID
    ,   OLD_NAME
    ,   OLD_DEPTNO          
    ,   OLD_LAWYER_ID       
    ,   OLD_COST           
    ,   OLD_BUDGET                
    ,   OLD_START_DATE             
    ,   OLD_END_DATE    
    ,   NEW_NAME
    ,   NEW_DEPTNO         
    ,   NEW_LAWYER_ID     
    ,   NEW_COST          
    ,   NEW_BUDGET           
    ,   NEW_START_DATE            
    ,   NEW_END_DATE
    ,   UPDATED    
    ,   UPDATED_BY  
    ,   MOD_TYPE       
    ) VALUES (
        PROJECTS_ARCH_ID_SEQ.nextval
    ,   :OLD.NAME
    ,   :OLD.DEPTNO         
    ,   :OLD.LAWYER_ID     
    ,   :OLD.COST          
    ,   :OLD.BUDGET           
    ,   :OLD.START_DATE            
    ,   :OLD.END_DATE
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL
    ,   NULL 
    ,   SYSDATE
    ,   user
    ,   'DELETE'
    )
    ;
END IF;
END;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BIU_PROJECTS" ENABLE
/

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "BIU_PROJ_MOD" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON PROJECTS
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF :new.id IS NULL THEN
    :new.id := PROJECTS_ID_SEQ.nextval;
    END IF;
    
    IF inserting THEN
    :new.created    := LOCALTIMESTAMP;
    :new.created_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
    END IF;
    :new.updated    := LOCALTIMESTAMP;
    :new.updated_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
END;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BIU_PROJ_MOD" ENABLE
```

PROCEDURE I tried to write

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bilans_counter_proc
(temp_budget number,
temp_cost number)
IS
BEGIN
    temp_budget := :new.BUDGET;
    temp_cost := :new.COST;
    INSERT INTO PROJECTS 
    (BILANS)
    VALUES (temp_budget-temp_cost);
    COMMIT;
END bilans_counter_proc;
```

ERROR that I GET:

```
Error at line 7: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.COST'
Error at line 6: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.BUDGET'


5. BEGIN
6.     temp_budget := :new.BUDGET;
7.     temp_cost := :new.COST;
8.     INSERT INTO PROJECTS 
9.     (BILANS)
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Please let me also know how to activate this auto-counting

Comment: `:NEW.` and `:OLD.` only have meaning within triggers. You can't use them in procedures. the place to do your calculation is in your trigger, not a procedure. Also, you don't need to say `:NEW.CREATED := LOCALTIMESTAMP`, just say `CREATED := LOCALTIMESTAMP`. `CREATED` references the column in your archive table that you want to update, while `:NEW.CREATED` is referencing the value of a column in the table that fired the trigger.

Comment: @pmdba Thank you for your answer. However, I still don't know how to "export" value that I need to "BILANS" column. I write AFTER INSERT/UPDATE Trigger, and what should be in this trigger and in the procedure  INSERT INTO PROJECTS?

Comment: Trying to store a value that can be computed at run time is a design flaw.  Instead of trying to store the value of 'budget - cost', just compute it when you need it.  If you try to store it, it is only a matter of time before some programming bug causes the stored/computed value to be incorrect.  Trust me on this.

Comment: @EdStevens
Thank you Ed. So what solution you recommend?  I wish that end user could insert new cost and budget would be automatically reduced by cost. 
Example. 
Lawyer gives the invoice for the Project to accountant. 
Accountant enters invoince into the system in table Invoices. 
In table Project, Lawyer can see how much budget he has left becuase it is reduced by invoice.
What is the best and the most professional way to do it?

Comment: Don't store the value at all. Calculate the value dynamically in a view or in your application logic so it is always accurate at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response guys! Now I know something more and I guess you must be right!